# Как в java быстро узнать кол-во знаков после точки?

Tags: java

Как узнать количество десятичных знаков в double?

Например есть число double со значением 12.345. Как мне быстро узнать и сохранить в переменную кол-во знаков после запятой?

Заранее спасибо!

```
double x = 12.345;
int i = 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double x = 12.345;
String[] splitter = String.valueOf(x).split("\\.");
int i = splitter[1].length(); 
//splitter[0].length() Это вернет нам количество знаков до запятой
```

Comment: Пишет ошибку: Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type double

Comment: Так должно работать, я проверил  с Double, а не с double :)

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.12345).scale()); // 5
```

Также работает для очень больших чисел в виде строки:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("2321.1234567890123456789").scale()); // 19
```

Только нужно опасаться использования `new BigDecimal(double)`, можно получить непредвиденные значения в силу того, что в `double` лежит не всегда именно то, что мы туда положили, а нечто очень похожее (некоторые значения невозможно представить точно в двоичной системе):

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(0.123);
System.out.println(d.scale()); // 52 ???
System.out.println(d.toString()); // 0.1229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 !!!
```

Comment: Надо без перевода в строку. А так ответ хороший!

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.12345).scale()` работает без перевода в строку.

Answer (score 3):

```
Double x = 12.345
Srting dstring = x.toString()
int decimalLen = dstring.length()-(dstring.indexOf(".")+1)
```

Comment: ВОТ ЭТО ужас... Double->String->length indexof.........  Я конечно понимаю это быстро пишется, но не надо учить плохому.

Comment: @Денис Котляров  автор не укзал, быстро что... быстро написать код или код, уоторый быстро это вычисляет...

Answer (score 2):

В цикле умножаешь на 10 и увеличиваешь счётчик пока x!=int(x)

Comment: Это хардкод называется!!!

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov хардкода тут нет, вы о чем?