# Сортировка массива double по количеству знаков после запятой

Tags: java, сортировка, double

Возможно ли быстро отсортировать массив типа double по количеству знаков после запятой?
Изначально хотела использовать словарь, где хранились бы сами числа и соответствующее количество знаков, но может есть способ проще?

Comment: Охо-хо... Нужно почитать про точность представления вещественных чисел. В общем случае то, что вы хотите - бессмысленно. Разве что ваши числа на самом деле рациональные.

Comment: @MBo, как раз в этой задаче ограниченная точность десятичных дробей худо-бедно обходится. Есть решение которое нормально выглядящие в коде значения обработает ожидаемым образом.

Comment: Спасибо за задачу! Узнал две новых вещи про Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сортировать массив примитивных значений (`double[]`, `int[]`, `long[]` и т.п.) можно только в "естественном" порядке.  Для необычной сортировки как в данном случае по длине дробной части потребуется либо использовать массив соответствующих классов-обёрток, т.е. `Double[]`, к которому можно применить метод [`Arrays::sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> comp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-), либо преобразовать с помощью Stream API.

*(Обновление) Для корректной сортировки нужно обеспечить ненулевое значение в старшем разряде (спасибо @Stanislav Volodarskiy).*

*Также потребуется обеспечить корректное форматирование некоторых чисел (спасибо @siarhei987), поскольку они могут быть по умолчанию преобразованы в строку с "научной" записью с указанием экспоненты.*
*Так как `double` может хранить до 17 значащих цифр, потребуется отформатировать каждое число, убрав нули в конце.  При форматировании следует принять во внимание локаль, чтобы корректно обрабатывался десятичный разделитель*

```java
Double[] arr = {
    1.234, 1.2, 22d, 1.001, 23.41, 10.00456, 3.1415, Math.PI
};

Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingLong(x -> {
    String s = String.format(Locale.US, "%.17f", x).replaceAll("0+$", "");
    return Long.parseLong(1 + s.substring(s.indexOf(".") + 1));
}));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// -> [22.0, 1.2, 23.41, 1.001, 1.234, 3.1415, 10.00456, 3.141592653589793]
```

Аналогично:

```java
double[] arr = {
    1.234, 1.2, 22, 1.001, 23.41, 10.00456, 3.1415, 11.21, Math.PI, 
    10.234, 1238.41,
    12345678.02,          // 10 знаков 8+2 
    12345678901234.5678,  // 18 знаков 14+4
    1234567890999.56789,  // 18 знаков 13+5
  -.123456789012345678,   // 18 знаков 0+18
-12.3456789012345678,     // 18 знаков 2+16
    987654321012345678.91 // 20 знаков 18+2
};

arr = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(
        x -> Long.parseLong(1 + String.format(Locale.US, "%.17f", x)
            .replaceAll("0+$", "")    // удалить 0 в конце
            .replaceAll("^.*\\.", "") // удалить всё до точки в начале
        )
    ))
    .mapToDouble(x -> x)
    .toArray();

for (double d : arr) {
    System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%.17f", d).replaceAll("\\.?0+$", ""));
}
```

Некоторые числа будут округлены, так как у типа `double` не хватает точности

```
22
987654321012345730
1.2
12345678.02
11.21
23.41
1238.41
1.001
1.234
10.234
12345678901234.568
3.1415
1234567890999.5679
10.00456
3.141592653589793
-12.345678901234567
-0.12345678901234568
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я поняла

Comment: что делать с числами типа `12345678.02`, например, для которых `Double#toString` вернёт строку на подобии  `1.234567802E7` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за комментарий, исправил

Comment: @siarhei987, хорошее замечание, пришлось допилить форматирование

Comment: увидел ответ на похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694717/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-java-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8?rq=1) . видимо, можно использовать  BigDecimal.valueOf(0.12345).scale() и не работать со строками.

Comment: Да, я видел этот ответ, но отбросил из-за варианта с конструктором `new BigDecimal(double d)`. Вариант с `BigDecimal.valueOf` хороший, хотя для моего примера `BigDecimal.valueOf(987654321012345678.91) -> -1`

Comment: При этом [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) конвертирует через [преобразование в строку](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java#L1269-L1275)

Answer (score 2):

`fracLength` вычисляет длину дробной части числа. `format` переводит `double` в десятичную дробь. `330` - волшебная константа: самое маленькое значение `double` - `4.9E-324`, значит трехсот тридцати знаков будет достаточно для любого конечного значения. Первый `replaceFirst` удаляет знак, целую часть и десятичную точку. Второй удаляет хвост из нулей. Длина остатка - то что нам нужно:

```
    private static int fracLength(double d) {
        return String
            .format("%.330f", d)
            .replaceFirst(".*\\.", "")
            .replaceFirst("0*$", "")
            .length();
    }
```

Java умеет сортировать `double[]` только по значениям. А нам нужно по ключу. Массив можно обернуть в список `List<Double>`. Приятно, что данные не надо копировать: новый список - интерфейс к массиву, не более:

```
    private static List<Double> wrap(double[] a) {
        return new AbstractList<Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double get(int index) {
                return a[index];
            } 

            @Override public int size() {
                return a.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Double set(int index, Double element) {
                final double previous = a[index];
                a[index] = element;
                return previous;
            }
        };
    }
```

Список уже можно сортировать по ключу. В результате сортируется сам массив:

```
    private static void sortByFracLength(double[] a) {
        Collections.sort(wrap(a), Comparator.comparingInt(d -> fracLength(d)));
    }
```

Тестируем решение:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Temp {
    private static List<Double> wrap(double[] a) {
        return new AbstractList<Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double get(int index) {
                return a[index];
            } 

            @Override public int size() {
                return a.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Double set(int index, Double element) {
                final double previous = a[index];
                a[index] = element;
                return previous;
            }
        };
    }

    private static int fracLength(double d) {
        return String
            .format("%.330f", d)
            .replaceFirst(".*\\.", "")
            .replaceFirst("0*$", "")
            .length();
    }

    private static void sortByFracLength(double[] a) {
        Collections.sort(wrap(a), Comparator.comparingInt(d -> fracLength(d)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a = {
            Double.MIN_VALUE,
            Double.MAX_VALUE,
            10.2,
            10.0001,
            1234,
            1234.01234
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        sortByFracLength(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Temp.java && java Temp
> [4.9E-324, 1.7976931348623157E308, 10.2, 10.0001, 1234.0, 1234.01234]
> [1.7976931348623157E308, 1234.0, 10.2, 10.0001, 1234.01234, 4.9E-324]
> ```

Comment: Не понятно, что такое «длина десятичной части числа», и почему для неё достаточно 330 знаков? Наименьшее положительное денормализованное число в _точном_ десятичном представлении имеет  `1074` знака после точки. Следующее большее число имеет `1073` знака после точки. Но если их округлить до `330` знаков, то они будут иметь одинаковую длину... ([Пример на C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c692f37a57c96140))

Comment: @wololo,  Java для `Double.MIN_VALUE` выдаёт 325 знаков (код я поменял, формат `"%.1080f"`). Могу форматировать сам, но пока не вижу смысла. Ваше замечание понятно. Ищу пример для менее экстремальных чисел - нужно чтобы "приличный" десятичный литерал был правильно обработан. "Приличны" означает что в десятичной записи он занимает 17 цифр (или меньше, как пойдёт). Если я добьюсь работы для любого числа с числом цифр "не более чем ..." буду считать задачу решённой полностью.